# Is there a way to search a field name in the design view of Table or Query?

Tags: ms-access, search

I heave a table with about 100 fields, when I want to edit a field I found a difficulty to visual search among such No. of fields.
The work around is copying one field to Excel then search on Excel for the specific field name, but if the layout view is not as design sort it is not helpful.

For queries I'm copying SQL code to Notepad or ms-word and do searches.
Is there a direct way to search a field name in the design view of a Table or a Query?

Comment: Table with 100 fields.... I smell a design problem.

Comment: [Microsoft Access tips: Where is a field used?](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-73.html)

Comment: @RobertHarvey you are right but it is an existing database I'm modifying.

Comment: @Rene Thank you, it is working but in immediate screen.   I want to search during modifying the design on the table or query

Comment: You could create a search form, enter a field name, call the functions and output to wherever you want to output to. This does require some knowledge of/experience with VBA though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in way for searching, but I use a free addon [Access Dependency Checker](http://www.accessdependencychecker.com/). It has many useful features, shows table/query structure, highlights a found field position and allows to open objects in design mode.

Comment: Thank you Sergey.  Very useful tool but didn't meet my needs, I know the table & the field name & want to find on the design view where is such field(s).

Comment: When you see field position in the search results, it's much easier to locate the field in design mode. Yes, it's not automatic, but it simplifies the task

Comment: Yes, you are right. if I right click a table or a query (listed inside Dependency Checker add-in) & select show details, it displayed the design of the table or the detailed fields & equation of the query as a text with search tool... Thanks Sergey